# Explode a string on every second occurrence of a character

Tags: php, regex, split, explode, preg-split

How would you explode a string of text on every second occurrence of a particular character?

```
$text = "Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.";
```

To explode on every dot, I'd use:

```
$domain_fragmented = explode(".", $text);
```

Is there a way to do that while splitting the string or I'd have to explode it and then implode it to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode on every dot, then put pairs of array entries back together again

```
$string = 'ab.cd.ef.gh.ij.kl.mn.op.qr';

$split = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return implode('.', $value);
    },
    array_chunk(explode('.', $string), 2)
);

var_dump($split);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fe4kt)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `preg_split` as follows:

```
$test = "this.is.a.test.to.see.how.preg_split.can.be.used.for.this";
$res = preg_split ("/(.*?\..*?)\./", $test, NULL,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($res);
```

**Output**

```
Array (
    [0] => this.is
    [1] => a.test
    [2] => to.see
    [3] => how.preg_split
    [4] => can.be
    [5] => used.for
    [6] => this
)
```

**Explanation**

The regular expression used here captures text up to, and including the second dot, and has a capture group that excludes that second dot. By specifying the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option, all matches for this captured group are included in the result.

Since every character in the original string will somehow be part of the splitting expression, the remaining parts, which are actually the normal result of the `split`, are all empty, except for maybe the ending part of the string. With the use of the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option these empty strings are excluded from the result.

The ending part of the string is not captured by the regular expression, because the final dot will be missing. But as the normal `split` behaviour adds that part to the array (as being split by the split-separator), we still get what we need, also for the ending part of the string.

NB: in my original answer I had put `\.|$` at the end of the regular expression, with the aim to recognise that last part of the string also as a separator, but with the above said, this is not necessary. It works without the `|$` part.

Comment: Can you explain the |$ in your regex? I know the terms but I don't know why you used this there. All tests I have run work well without it.

Comment: You are right, you can remove it (together with the pipe). It will give the same result, but in some cases via a different route. The `$` stands for "end of the string", and the idea is to consider the match fine, even if there is no second dot, but only if you're at the end of the string. Without the `$` there is no match for the last "group", but that is still OK, because preg_split will regard that as a result of a normal split (which is not empty), and include it. So end result is the same in both cases. Considering this, I will remove it from my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using pre_match_all?

```
/(?:(?:.+?\.){2})/
```

With this you get a list containing two sentences (delimited with a dot) per list item.

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all(
    '/(?:(?:.+?\\.){2})/',
    '
        1_Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. 
        2_According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.
        3_Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. 
        4_According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.',
    $matches
);
```

This returns the following in $matches:

```
array (
    0 => array (
        0 => '1_Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. 2_According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.',
        1 => '3_Online groceries is one of the few channels to market that is growing, though its profitability is questionable. 4_According to industry research group IGD the UK online grocery market will nearly double to 18 billion pounds in the five years to 2020.',
    )
)
```

Sadly, this is not perfect. I did not succeed in capturing any additional text that dangles at the end of the input string (e.g. "sentence1.sentence2.bla"). So, if you (or someone else) can't come up with an improved regex that captures this (that is, is you need this to be captured; if you know the input string always consists of paired sentences then all is good already) you might want to trim away what is captured with pre_match_all. The rest must therefore be the rest :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will go with explode/implode function as it works well and is simpler to implement

Answer (score 0):

The most direct/appropriate function to call for this task is `preg_split()`. The pattern itself will have best performance if greedy quantifiers are used and there are no capture groups.  For these reasons, my regex is more streamlined than trincot's regex.

Match a literal dot, then zero or more non-dots, then "forget" those matched characters with `\K`, then match the next literal dot -- this will "consume" only every second dot during each split.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ffi6O))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '/\.[^.]*\K\./',
        $string,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```